# Adding a Background color in iron router

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, iron-router

I have two separate pages I am trying to add a background color to whilst using Iron Router, so the html has no  tags to use.

I see that Router.onBeforeAction(function() {

}); exists and that seems to be the way to do this.

So any thoughts on how to add the CSS styling would be greatly thanks.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function(){
    this.route('Main', {path: '/', data: {title: 'Contacts Admin'}, name: 'mainlanding'});
    this.route('Contact', {path: '/Contact', data: {title: 'Contacts List'}, name: 'contactlanding'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this in your route:

js:

```
onAfterAction: function(){
  $('.mySpecialClass').remove('mySpecialClass'); // undo what was done before
  $('body').addClass('mySpecialClass'); // add a class
}
```

css:

```
.mySpecialClass {
  background-color: "red";
}
```

Comment: Michel 
$(.mySpecialClass') is wrong as you have a spare ' at the end.

I don't have any <body> tags so will it add it?

Comment: This compiles but the screen is blank.
Router.map(function(){
  this.route('Main', {path: '/', data: {title: 'Contacts Admin'},
                      onBeforeAction: function(){
                        $(.myColourClass).remove('myColourClass');
                        $('body').addClass('myColourClass'); 
                      }
                     });
 ...

Comment: Fixed the mismatched quotes. Meteor will put the `<body>` in the html for you. I just used that as an illustrative selector, it could be whatever you want that's in your html.

Comment: The body works but still now coloured background.

I changed to onRun and added this.next(); at the end. I can now see the pages.

Comment: My HTML only contains only templates.

Comment: Normally you would just put a `<div class='myClass'>` in your template to be able to target it with css.

Comment: I have added the <div> tags for both of my switching templates but sadly still no colour.

Maybe they are in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible, but routing code is not the right place to define background colors for your pages.

In each template include the appropriate css classes you need to apply the background color.

If you need something more complex than that (color depends on state, etc) use a template helper to assign the class you want based on the state.

Comment: Agree with this btw. The one use I've found for DOM manipulation in the router is to [set the active menu in the nav](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html) since that depends on the route and you want to clear the previous state as well.

Comment: I've also used a similar pattern.  In this case the part of the DOM being manipulated is like another view of the url, so seems acceptable to use the router hooks in this way.